# How to batch convert JPG image gallery to BPG image format

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, bpg

How to convert whole image gallery or family album from JPG to BPG image format?
I'm looking for some batch conversion tool, application or script on Windows platform.
Input directory must be processed recursively and image quality should be preserved.

Comment: Why would you want to use BPG format?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, To save up space. Some photos serve well as a memory even while being 30KB in size.

Answer (score 2):

Linux command line fragment I use for this task, with current directory being gallery of '*.JPG' files, without subdirectories.

```
parallel -i sh -c 'convert -quality 100 {} -scale "1280x1000>" {}.png &&  bpgenc -q 30 {}.png -o {}.bpg && rm -f {}.png' -- *.JPG
```

You may adjust (or remove) resizing and change `-q 30` to lower value for more quality.

It depends on ImageMagick and bpgenc.

To run in on Windows, you probably will need Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Look at
http://www.romeolight.com/products/bpgconv/
for nice Windows converter.

2 things to mention: Currently there is options menu in top right of window. And all BPG pictures are saved into folder on your desktop called bpg_encoded.

Martin